# CCNET Config Conditional Task Execution

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

Hi all require help on CCNet Conditional execution.

These are  the Triggers I have declared

> ```
>   <intervalTrigger
>            name="continuous"
>            seconds="30"
>            buildCondition="IfModificationExists"
>            initialSeconds="5"/>
>
>   <scheduleTrigger time="23:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="scheduled">
>     <weekDays>
>       <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
>     </weekDays>
>   </scheduleTrigger>
> </triggers>
> ```

Below is the Task I am Having both to be triggered based on Condition

```
 <conditional>
  <conditions>
    <compareCondition value1="$[buildCondition]"
      value2="IfModificationExists"  />
  </conditions>
    <tasks>
     <msbuild >
     <executable>...\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
     <workingDirectory>...\WcfServiceLibrary1\</workingDirectory>
     <projectFile>MSBuild_MasterConfigFile.BUILD</projectFile>
     <buildArgs>/target:CCNETBUILD /p:Config=Debug</buildArgs>
     <timeout>900</timeout>
   </msbuild>
```

```
    <elseTasks>
      <msbuild ><executable>...\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <workingDirectory>...\WcfServiceLibrary1\</workingDirectory>
      <projectFile>MSBuild_MasterConfigFile.BUILD</projectFile>
      <buildArgs>/target:CCNETDeploy /p:Config=Debug</buildArgs>
      <timeout>900</timeout>
    </msbuild>
  </elseTasks>
</conditional>
```

I am getting unused node detected exception. Please help me asap. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to tell from your code sample, but did you check that the `<Conditionals>` node is embedded within a `<tasks>...</tasks>` node in your project declaration?
In other words:

```
<project>
<tasks>
<conditional>...</conditional>
</tasks>
</project>
```

and not

```
<project>
<conditional>...</conditional>
</project>
```